# Azure Search, listAdminKeys, ARM output error (does not support http method 'POST')

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-cognitive-search, azure-rm-template

I am using this bit of code as an output object in my ARM template,

```
    "[listAdminKeys(variables('searchServiceId'), '2015-08-19').PrimaryKey]"
```

Full text sample of the output section:

```
    "outputs": {
     "SearchServiceAdminKey": {
       "type": "string",
       "value": "[listAdminKeys(variables('searchServiceId'), '2015-08-19').PrimaryKey]"
      },

     "SearchServiceQueryKey": {
       "type": "string",
       "value": "[listQueryKeys(variables('searchServiceId'), '2015-08-19')[0]]"
      }
```

I receive the following error during deployment (unfortunately, any error means the template deployment skips output section):

```
    "The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'."
```

Checking the browser behavior seems to validate the error is related to the function (and, it using POST).

[listAdminKeys using POST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3ndZ.png)

How might I avoid this error and retrieve the AzureSearch admin key in the output?

Update: the goal of doing this is to gather all the relevant bits of information to plug into other scripts (.ps1) as parameters, since those resources are provisioned by this template. Would save someone from digging through the portal to copy/paste.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You error comes from listQueryKeys, not admin keys.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchmanagement/adminkeys/get
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchmanagement/querykeys/listbysearchservice

you wont be able to retrive those in the arm template, it can only "emulate" POST calls, not GET

Comment: Thank you. I see I was misunderstanding the error text. It's complaining that listQueryKeys cannot support POST, not that listAdminKeys does support POST.

Answer (score 1):

With the latest API version, it's possible to get the query key using this:

```
     "SearchServiceQueryKey": {
       "type": "string",
       "value": "[listQueryKeys(variables('searchServiceId'), '2020-06-30').value[0].key]"
      }
```